# "Standard sharepoint icons"?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm a rookie in sharepoint and trying to create pages etc. that's ok for me. But when I'm trying to find "standard icons" such as power point, then I'm lost.

Is there any library for such icons?

BR Toby

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add powerpoint icon in page? Or want to create powerpoint files in SharePoint online?

If the former, you can use [Office UI Fabric icons](https://uifabricicons.azurewebsites.net/) in SPFx webpart as stated in below official documentation by Microsoft:

[Usage of the Office UI Fabric icons in SPFx components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration#usage-of-the-office-ui-fabric-icons-in-spfx-components).

If the later, please go to a library then click New as shown below:

[image]

If it is not feasible for you, please feel free to reply.